# Has anybody tried to check out mahout (SVN) from eclipse (subclipse)

Tags: svn, mahout

I was trying to check out a copy of mahout using the subclipse.

I typed in the following link to try to create a new reposistory location, but failed. Did I do something wrong? Thanks

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/mahout/trunk

The error message is below

"Error validating location: "org.tigris.subversion.javahl.ClentException:RA layer request failed
svn: OPTIONS of 'http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/mahout/trunk/':
Could not resolve hostname 'svn.apache.org': No such host is known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you had internet access on that machine? And that DNS was resolving correctly? That address is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Mahout has become a TLP in apache and so the repository url is  http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/mahout/trunk

You can read more about the download and install instructions from httpscolon//cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAHOUT/BuildingMahout.It has notes on configuring mahout in eclipse.